# Debian ssh user TAB behaviour changed - how to revert it?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, tab-key

I have created new user with:

```
useradd u 
passwd u
```

When logged as `u` via `PuTTy` the TAB key behaviour is changed:

- autofill dir/filenames and commands not working
- the tab is placed instaed (4 spaces)
- When moving coursor with ARROW LEFT it writes `^[[D`

Also noticed other keys behave different:

- END and HOME buttons go to start/end of line ARROW

And other just fine:

- UP, ARROW DOWN normally scroll thru history

I dont mind END and HOME, but TAB needs to be autofill instaed of 4 spaces. Wierd is that all my previous machines behaved normally. This one is a dedicated server from new provider with Linux Debian Wheezy provided.

PS `root` user's TAB works fine :)

Comment: Have you checked your .bashrc?

Comment: It's all comments for root user, where faulty user `u` has no such file as `~/.bashrc`. In fact had to manually create `~` for new user

Answer (score 0):

Found answer @ https://serverfault.com/questions/399852/bash-tab-completion-only-works-for-root

My user had `:/bin/sh` setting, while root was `:/bin/bash` - chanded `sh` to `bash` :-)